# queryparam in extjs combo

Tags: extjs, extjs4

i am passing a url to my store's proxy and need to pass a query parameter to it.I tried using queryParam :'q'.When i use this,in firebug i see q="whatever i type",this returns me the entire list of data irrespective of whatever i type.Actually the way want to pass the parameter is different.If i do this in my proxy,

```
extraParams:{
 q:'selectedType:'+'whatever i type' 
}
```

This matches the way i need to pass whatever i type to the server but does not work because i have used queryParam :'q' also.But if i do not use queryParam :'q',it gives me a network error and by default the whatever i type is passed to 'query'.Basically, i want to append whatever i type after 'selectedType:'. Is there a way i can do this.Any help is appreciated....thanks

Comment: it's not standard thing, who made this? Read IETF's RFC for this : `Many URL schemes reserve certain characters for a special meaning:
   their appearance in the scheme-specific part of the URL has a
   designated semantics. If the character corresponding to an octet is
   reserved in a scheme, the octet must be encoded.  The characters ";",
   "/", "?", ":", "@", "=" and "&" are the characters which may be
   reserved for special meaning within a scheme. No other characters may
   be reserved within a scheme.`

Answer (score 0):

you need to override 'doRawQuery' with:

```
doRawQuery: function() {
    this.doQuery('selectedType:' + this.getRawValue(), false, true);
}
```

this will calles before a query will start.